# Problems using printf and scanf with JNA

Tags: java, jna

I wrote some Java JNA beginner code.  I built it with no compilation errors.

I download JNA 5.6 from [here](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/tree/master/dist/).

I am only seeing output from this command:

```
System.out.println( "Hello" );
```

Why doesn't it work?

```java
package layout;
import com.sun.jna.Library;
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.Platform;
    
interface JNAApiInterface extends Library {
    @SuppressWarnings( "deprecation")
    JNAApiInterface INSTANCE = (JNAApiInterface) Native.loadLibrary(
            Platform.isWindows() ? "msvcrt" : "c", JNAApiInterface.class);
    void printf( String format, Object... args );
    int sprintf( byte[] buffer, String format, Object... args );
    int scanf( String format, Object... args );
}
    
public class JNA01 {
    public static void main( String args[] ) {
        System.out.println( "Hello" );
        JNAApiInterface jnaLib = JNAApiInterface.INSTANCE;
        jnaLib.printf( "Hello World" );
        String testName = null;
        jnaLib.printf( "Please Enter Your Name: \n" );
        jnaLib.scanf( "%s", testName );
        jnaLib.printf( "\nYour name is %s", testName ); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JNA mappings are correct, but you are not properly using the native function.

The `scanf()` function requires you to allocate memory for a buffer to fill with the `testName` value, but you have passed it an immutable `String` with a null value!

The program prints the first `Hello` and actually has printed `Hello WorldPlease Enter Your Name:` , but your IDE may not yet display this stdout as it is awaiting the input from the `scanf()`. If you actually enter a value you'll get a segmentation fault as it tries to write your entered name to unallocated memory!

To fix the problem, you need to allocate a buffer to fill.  Assign a byte array to `testNum`, which JNA will automatically reserve the allocated memory for.  Then decode the bytes using `Native.toString()`.

This version of your main loop works:

```java
public static void main(String args[]) {
    System.out.println("Hello");
    JNAApiInterface jnaLib = JNAApiInterface.INSTANCE;
    jnaLib.printf("Hello World\n");
    // this is dangerous as you don't control how long user input is
    // but for learning it's fine, you will crash with longer names
    byte[] testName = new byte[100]; 
    jnaLib.printf("Please Enter Your Name: \n");
    jnaLib.scanf("%s", testName);
    jnaLib.printf("\nYour name is %s", Native.toString(testName));
}
```